# What is the current limiting factor for GPS clock synchronization precision?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atmospheric-science, experimental-technology, gps

In the (slightly dated) paper 'Quantum Clock Synchronization Based on Shared Prior Entanglement' [R. Jozsa et al., [*Phys. Rev. Lett.* **85**, 2010 (2000)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.85.2010)], the authors describe the GPS synchronization abilities as being limited by atmospheric fluctuations:

> in the GPS satellite constellation, the ability of the space-borne atomic clocks to synchronize with a master atomic clock on the ground is affected by the fluctuating refractive index of the atmosphere, causing random variations in the speed of light and limiting the accuracy of the classical ES [Einstein Synchronization] protocol. This index fluctuation error is the current limiting factor of GPS precision [11].
>
> $\cdots$
>
> 11. National Research Council Staff, *The Global Positioning System: A Shared National Asset* (National Academy Press, Washington, DC, 1995).

However, the paper is more than fifteen years old, and things may well have changed since then. So: is this mechanism still the main limiting factor for the synchronization precision for GPS clocks? If not, then what is the current bottleneck, and how was the atmospheric-fluctuation problem solved?

Comment: There is a newer paper by Delva et al. [2017] (doi:10.1007/s11214-017-0361-9) in Space Science Reviews that addresses tests that can be performed with accurate clocks in space.  While not directly addressing your question, it may have some good references of more recent engineering constraints.

Comment: Another paper on clocks in Space Science Reviews just came out (doi:[10.1007/s11214-017-0431-z](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11214-017-0431-z)) that focuses entire on using clocks to measure gravity fields.  I have not had a chance to read it yet, but it may be interesting to you.